# Variável se mantém zerada em uma expressão matemática

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, matemática, tipagem

O meu programinha está assim:

```
        public void CalculaProporção()
    {
        decimal contagemSubida = 0 , contagemDescida = 0;
        int cSubida = 6, cDescida = 4, range = 10;
        contagemSubida += Convert.ToDecimal(cSubida*range/100);
        contagemDescida += Convert.ToDecimal(cDescida*range/100);

        contagemSubida = contagemSubida + Convert.ToDecimal(contagemSubida * (4/10));
        contagemDescida = contagemDescida + Convert.ToDecimal(contagemDescida * (4/10));
    }
```

Minhas variáveis contagemSubida e contagemDescida ficam com o valor 0 durante todo o procedimento, o que devo fazer para elas calcularem corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está fazendo uma conversão desnecessária e tarde demais. Quando você faz uma divisão com inteiros, você terá resultado como inteiro, e o inteiro do resultado obtido é 0 mesmo. Se quer a parte decimal precisa usar um dado decimal, seja por uma variável que já é `decimal` ou um literal desse número. O literal do tipo `decimal` sempre vem acompanhado o sufixo `M` de *money*, já que este tipo costuma ser usado para valor monetário. Sem o sufixo é por padrão um inteiro, e aí dá problema. Assim deve dar o resultado que espera:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        decimal contagemSubida = 0 , contagemDescida = 0;
        int cSubida = 6, cDescida = 4, range = 10;
        contagemSubida += cSubida * range / 100M;
        contagemDescida += cDescida * range / 100M;
        contagemSubida += contagemSubida * (4 / 10M);
        contagemDescida += contagemDescida * (4 / 10M);
        WriteLine(contagemSubida);
        WriteLine(contagemDescida);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xEALCI). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zxdCPz). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/%20DecimalLiteral.cs).

Note que se mudar o tipo das variáveis secundárias para `decimal` o resultado poderá ser outro sem que mude o divisor para o tipo `decimal` e não parece ser o que deseja, embora não posso afirmar porque a pergunta não diz qual deveria ser o resultado.

Comment: Perfeito! Entendi a linha de raciocínio, apliquei e deu certinho :D

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se foi seu corretor mas não costuma-se usar acentuação na programação.

Altera o tipo de dados pra decimal:

```
decimal cSubida = 6, cDescida = 4, range = 10;
```

Exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/clVoHU

Comment: Como a solução acima, esse modelo também funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda  :D